# Matrix4 Transition in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create a smooth transition with zoom in my code but it doesn't behave as expected, what am I doing wrong??

So I'm making the transition.

```
Widget _buildPageItem (int index){
    //trabalhando o zoom usando a funcao intstate
    Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4.identity();
    if (index == _currPageValue.floor()){
      var currScale = 1-(_currPageValue-index)*(1-_scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height*(1-currScale)/2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);

    }else if (index == _currPageValue.floor()+1){
      var currScale = _scaleFactor+(_currPageValue-index+1)*(1-_scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height*(1-currScale)/2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
    }else if (index == _currPageValue.floor()-1){
      var currScale = 1-(_currPageValue-index)*(1-_scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height*(1-currScale)/2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
    }else{
      var currScale = 0.8;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, _height*(1-_scaleFactor)/2, 1);
    }
```

the return Transform function

Answer (score 0):

Last else{} should look like this:

```
}else{
      var currScale = 0.8;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)..setTranslationRaw(0, _height*(1-_scaleFactor)/2, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// For Matrix4 Transition in Flutter, we do the following code:-

// Declare these variables according to your requirement, I have taken values just for an example -

 PageController pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85);
 var _currPageValue = 0.0;
 double _scaleFactor = 0.8;
 double _height = 220;

// Add this code in init and dispose widget -

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _currPageValue = pageController.page!;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

// Add this code after the above -

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 320,
      child: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _buildPageItem(position);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPageItem(int index) {
    Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4.identity();
    if (index == _currPageValue.floor()) {
      var currScale = 1 - (_currPageValue - index) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
    } else if (index == _currPageValue.floor() + 1) {
      var currScale =
          _scaleFactor + (_currPageValue - index + 1) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
    } else if (index == _currPageValue.floor() - 1) {
      var currScale = 1 - (_currPageValue - index) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
      var currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1);
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
    } else {
      var currScale = 0.8;
      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
        ..setTranslationRaw(0, _height * (1 - _scaleFactor) / 2, 1);
    }

    return Transform(
      transform: matrix,
      child: Container()
    );
  }

// I hope you will be able to scale factor the current widget while sliding it.
```